# Active or passive

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

The blocks are well fitted. Is it Active or passive sentence?
It seems active but I am not sure whether the verb fitted is tranistive or not

Comment: Which word do you think is the verb here?

Comment: I think it is Fitted.

Answer (score -1):

'To fit' is a transitive verb in this sentence. It means 'to adjust, to tailor something'.
The verb in the sentence is in the Present Simple Passive.

Comment: But it's used adjectivally. You can't say "I well fitted the blocks." So it's not passive.

Comment: It IS Passive. The absence of the logical subject can be easily reconstructed: '... by builders'.

Comment: 'Fitted' is a verb form as it is modified by an adverb 'well'.

Comment: The sentence with Active Voice would be: 'I fitted the blocks well'.

Comment: Then the passive sentence would be "the blocks were fitted well".

Comment: I believe this could be either a passive or active, it depends on the context. E.g. if one would look at a wall of blocks one could say the 'The blocks are well fitted' (in the wall). But if one speaks about the characteristics of the blocks themselves, then it would not be a passive sentence.